# Constructing an infinite chain of subsets of 'hyper' algebraic numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, fields, transcendental-number-theory

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3014759/constructing-an-infinite-chain-of-subfields-of-hyper-algebraic-numbers) is cross posted from MSE.

Let $F$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $S_F$ denote the set of values which satisfy some generalized polynomial whose exponents and coefficients are drawn from $F$. 
That is, we let $S_F$ denote
$$\bigg \{x \in \mathbb{R}: 0=\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i x^{e_i}}: e_i \in F \text{ distinct}, a_i\in F \text{ non-zero}, n\in \mathbb{N}  \bigg  \}$$

Then $S_{\mathbb{\mathbb{Q}}}$ is the set of algebraic real numbers and we start to see the beginnings of a chain:

$
\mathbb{Q}
\subsetneq S_\mathbb{Q} \subsetneq
S_{S_\mathbb{Q}} $

**Main Question**

> Does this chain continue forever? That is, we let $A_0= \mathbb{Q}$ and let $A_{n+1}=S_{A_{n}}$. Is it the case that $A_n \subsetneq A_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

**Other curiosities:**

Is $A_i$ always a field? Perhaps, the argument is analogous to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331017/enlightening-proof-that-the-algebraic-numbers-form-a-field). Or maybe this is just the case in a more general setting: Is it the case that $F \subset \mathbb{R}$, a field implies that $S_F$ is a field?

Is it possible to see that $e\notin \cup A_i$? Perhaps this is just a tweaking of [LW Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

Comment: This is my first Q here and I am happy to modify anything. I know the tone of this website is slightly distinct from MSE. If you want to suggest edits feel free to ping me.

Comment: Welcome to Math Overflow.

Comment: AFAIK it could just well be that $e\in A_2$, and I wouldn't really hope for a proof one way or the other. Assuning Schanuel's conjecture might give you some results, though

Comment: @Wojowu. I think $e\notin A_2$ is precisely what LW gives us. You may mean $A_3$? Note that $\cup A_i$ is countable. So we should expect that an arbitrary real number is not a member of $\cup A_i$. However: Expectations are not mathematical proofs.

Comment: @Mason Right, for some reason I thought $A_1$ already contains numbers of the sort $2^{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: A [related MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59972/transcendental-numbers-yet-another-classification.) from 7 years before this one. Truly there is nothing new under the sun: The above post calls them "extra" algebraic as opposed to "hyper" algebraic and (in the comments) define $A_0$ as the algebraic reals. Where here I let $A_1$ denote the algebraic numbers.